# Audio tag in Safari

Tags: html, audio, safari

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script language=javascript src="scripts/lib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="track09.wav">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

It does work in FF4, but doesn't in Safari 5.0.5 under Winx64. How should I fix it?

Thx.

UPDATED. Both mp3 and html files are local, not stored on server side.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different format than .wav - encode your audio in mp3 and ogg and include both formats in your markup like this:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="track09.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="track09.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

You can get a utility to do the encoding for you from http://audacity.sourceforge.net

This will cover all browsers that currently support html5 audio.

Comment: I tried <source src="track09.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />, but to no avail. Maybe, it's because both mp3 and html files are local?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, but make sure the path to the file is correct. That path will only work if the file is in the same directory as the html. I'm also assuming you encoded the mp3 file from the wav using the utility from the link?

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is little edited.**

Add type for source. I've tested in Safari. This code works for me.

```
  <source src="track09.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
```

The other solution (for Safari) is to use AAC codec. It doesn't work in Firefox.

```
  <source src="track09.aac" type="audio/aac" />
```

You may use Ogg Vorbis for Firefox. It probably doesn't work in Safari.

```
  <source src="track09.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
```

It looks there isn't any universal codec. You have to encode Your sound few times or don't support few browsers.

P.S.
It looks mp3 doesn't work anywhere for me.

Comment: I tried <source src="track09.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />, but to no avail. Maybe, it's because both mp3 and html files are local?

Answer (score 0):

For local testing it does not matter if the files are local, so are the html files.
the solution is not obvious at the first sight.

The Safari browser relies on Apple Quicktime to support the Audio tag.
If you download the Safari-Browser for testing purposes it will not work.
You need the complete package as Safari uses the Codec of Quicktime to support playback.

look here:
[HTML5Tutorial](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php)

Furthermore the MP3 should be on the first place that safari can recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution IMHO is to use multiple source files and [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Ekaterina,

Safari 5 does not play audio by itself. It needs QuickTime installed on Windows. Do that, and probably will work (If you still need it, since it was asked 2 years ago!)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2544849?start=0&tstart=0