# Cant play audio via Safari 5.1 web

Tags: html

Audio plays ok in other browsers Chrome, FF, Opera but there seems to be an issue with Safari 5.1. Is there an error with my code?

It simply should start playing upon page load.

```
<audio autoplay><source src="music/tune.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Try adding `type="audio/mp3"` to your `audio` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hie,

This thread at Apple Supports discuss this point which is refered at [Audio tag in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333739/audio-tag-in-safari):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2544849?start=0&tstart=0

This questions provides some ways to make workarounds [Safari with audio tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804028/safari-with-audio-tag-not-working).

As you can see on those questions and topics, Safari `audio` tag is related to your Quicktime.

And this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FallbackHTML5AudioTagsForASimpleMP3PodcastAreHarderThanYoudThink.aspx) also is helpful.

Thanks