# Safari audio tag and css not working (On windows, Safari 5.7.1)

Tags: html, css, safari

Okay I have a simple page that autoplays and loops music in the background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>One Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #showcase {
            background-image: url('test.jpeg');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main id="showcase">
        <audio autoplay loop>
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
            <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

This code works great on Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work on Safari.

The image is not responsive (full screen) and the audio isn't playing, I get:

*Your browser does not support the audio element.*
on the page.

I download the latest version of Safari on my windows. I've tried a couple of solutions, but none some to work.
I haven't seen any solutions for the **mp3** format.

Comment: safari for windows is no longer supported.

Comment: @Daniel What ? So how can I test my page for safari ? I have to buy a mac ? >:(((

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio tag in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333739/audio-tag-in-safari)